# Long sentence construction

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

The scenario is that the protagonist, Alice, had Alzheimer's and was running through by her doctor some  cognitive tests, and one of which was Boston naming Exam.
She failed to name a hammock.
As her doctor noted that down, she wanted to argue.

Here's the long sentence I have trouble understanding.

> Alice wanted to argue that her omission could just **as easily** have been a normal case of blocking **as a symptom of Alzheimer's.**

-cited from [Still Alice](http://www.freebookol.net/Still_Alice/16.html)

I know the author is saying that "failed to name a word could have been as easily mistaken as an Alzheimer's symptom"(or is she not?)

I can understand the sentence without words in bold, but altogether, I can't.

I found a similar sentence which makes more sense to me.

> This could have just as easily happened to a catholic school as a public school.

[cited from here](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=as%20easily&l=0&t=0&sugg=off)

Please explain the first sentence construction for me.
Thank you!

Comment: ***just as easily** X **as** Y* means that both X and Y are equally likely (in Alice's opinion).

Comment: @Mick Can I paraphrase the sentence into *could have been **just as easily** a normal case of blocking[X] **as** a symptom of Alzheimer's[Y]?*

Comment: It doesn't sound right to me. You need an expert's opinion. (But add your paraphrase to your question.)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern

> just as easily *A* as *B*

means both *A* and *B* are equally likely possibilities.

> I could have *just as easily* walked to work *as* ridden a bike.

Your example's construction is

> **could** *just as easily* **have been** a normal case of blocking *as* a symptom of Alzheimer's.

where each case in the parallel construction is

> that her omission **could have been** *a normal case of blocking*
>    that her omission **could have been** *a symptom of Alzheimer's*

Comment: Can I paraphrase the sentence into *could have been **just as easily** a normal case of blocking[A] **as** a symptom of Alzheimer's[B]?*